# Service published in IIS says "Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled"

Tags: wcf, iis

I use VS2010 Win 2008 R2. I created a "WCF service library", put it in a virtual directory in IIS and converted that to an application.

I put the svc file in root of the application and changed the output build path to `bin`. Every time when try the URL `http://localhost/test1/Service1.svc` I receive the error *"Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled"*.

I also tried the URL `http://localhost/test1/MEX`. Mex behavior is configured correctly but this error appears.

When I try to add a service reference to a console application it also can't find metadata for service.

Comment: What have you tried to find? Please show the relevant parts (system.serviceModel section) of your web.config. Also, is the `bin` directory inside the `test1` directory? Also, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917761/wcf-metadata-publishing-for-this-service-is-currently-disabled-content-type-er) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290323/solve-wcf-error-metadata-publishing-for-this-service-is-currently-disabled) since they contain quite a few useful answers you can check.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share you configuration file serviceBehavior section?

It should be something like this to enable Metadata exchange.

```
<serviceBehaviors>
   <behavior name="SampleServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
   </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
     <service name="WcfServiceLibrary4.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/test/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
           contract="WcfServiceLibrary4.IService1"/>

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I first enabled anonymous access to virtual folder and after that I saw "Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled."-error.
I tried "http://localhost/test/mex" but IIS says "no such resource". Here I mention "test" not "test1" because I change the virtual folder. Bin folder is under Test and output from build of project I set to Bin not Bin/Debug.